Cannot uninstall outlook add-in
I have built an outlook add-in using the teams toolkit, and have deployed it via my company's microsoft admin centre. It works great for other users but I seem to have ended up with a mix of the local manifest and the live manifest. I will often find that the add-in doesn't work for me unless I'm running the code locally, also when I try and stop the add-in from running locally, using npm run stop, I get a 403 error when it tries to remove the add-in.
The command that is erroring seems to be npx @microsoft/teamsapp-cli uninstall "--title-id" U_1bb66615-4f23-7bcd-7794-ccd49896a4a8
and the error looks like this...
Error: m365.InternalError: Request failed with status code 403 (tracingId: 00-6ec0d36dd0181523e6e8bbac62b628f6-df6f2b53efdc3f13-00) Forbidden: Exception of type 'Services.Core.Common.Contract.Exceptions.ForbiddenException' was thrown.
I am at a loss with what the error could be, but when I list my installed add-ins via web or desktop it does show 2 versions, 1 is the admin managed one, which is fine, but the other cannot be deleted. I see a remove button but it also errors.
This is how my add-ins are listed

This is the error when I try and remove it via the UI

Literally anything I could try would be much appreciated

you seem to have tried: Turn an add-in off for Outlook for Windows, but maybe try this too: Remove a custom outlook addin

Thanks for the links, I seem to be in the same position as the last person to comment on the remove one. But on the web the addin that relates to my local one comes back when I refresh

Try to enable logging, or contact your Administrator.

Thanks, definitely will get someone with more access to have a look for me. I turned on the logging but the outlook addin error doesn't seem to add anything to the log files, will keep logging on for a bit though and see
